# How to add widget automatically or dynamically into program?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

Firstly, I am new to kivy. I want to add the selection widget(like button, check box, toggle button into my program based on the data(as in list by reading from the csv file). In other words, that the number of adding new widget must change according to data from csv file.[image]

I would like to add these new widgets into the blue circle section(box layout). 
Kind Regards, 
John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a box layout with a method adding desired widgets. Example:

```
class BoxLayoutWithBlueCircle(BoxLayout):

    def add_buttons(self, how_many):
        self.clear_widgets()

        for i in range(how_many):
            button = Button(text='button_{}'.format(i))
            # add here more attributes, like size
            self.add_widget(button)
```

Each time you call the method, a set of buttons will be added to the instance of `BoxLayoutWithBlueCircle`. You can bind it to a button.

Comment: Is it also possible to remove the created buttons inside that Boxlayout via program.

Comment: @MooreJohn90 Method `clear_widgets` does that. You can call it directly just like `add_buttons`.

Comment: Thanks a lot  @jligeza

Comment: Sure i will @jiligeza

Comment: Hi jiligeza, I also want to create a new window(widget) for getting adding new info as in input form when the user click on "Add New Item" button. How do I link the button and new form widget.

Comment: @MooreJohn90 I guess the form widget has some inputs and a submit button? So, first create the form class based on a box layout. Then, bind its creation to a button's `on_release` event, preferably in kv file. Inside the form, implement a `submit` method, which will do anything you want, and at the end remove itself with `self.parent.remove_widget(self)`. I recommend you checking kivy's IRC, where people help each other at such tasks.

Comment: Thanks you @jiligeza